# Error: React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'setAPIData'. Either include it or remove the dependency array.eslintreact-hooks/exhaustive-deps

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, developer-tools

Facing issue that "React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'setAPIData'. Either include it or remove the dependency array.eslintreact-hooks/exhaustive-deps", tried so many possible ways but still facing the same issue.

function Read() {

```
const { APIdata, setAPIData } = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
    const getApiData = async () => {
        const res = await axios.get(API);
        setAPIData(res.data);
    }
    getApiData();
}, []);
```

**console error Screenshot:**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LWUTn.png)

Comment: `tried so many possible ways` - did you try doing wha tthe error message told you to do?

Comment: Your screenshot and your post have 2 different error messages

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't actually answer your question, but it will answer the question that you'll have next:

```
const { APIdata, setAPIData } = useState([]);
```

is wrong, it should be:

```
const [ APIdata, setAPIData ] = useState([]);
```